# react typescript issue on addEvenListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have got below implementation which works fine if I don't worry about typescript.

```
  const escFunction: (event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => any = useCallback((event: React.KeyboardEvent["keydown"]) => {
    if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.ESC) {
      closeFn();
    }
  }, [closeFn]);

  if (closeTimeout) {
    setTimeout(closeFn, closeTimeout);
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldCloseOnEsc) {
      document.addEventListener(KEY_EVENT.KEYDOWN, escFunction, false);
    }
    return () => {
      if (shouldCloseOnEsc) {
        document.removeEventListener(KEY_EVENT.KEYDOWN, escFunction, false);
      }
    }
  }, [shouldCloseOnEsc, escFunction]);
```

But `document.addEventListener` and `document.addEventListener` are showing typescript error as below:

```
TypeScript error in /mnt/d/Projects/sb-modal/src/components/modal/Modal.tsx(63,7):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "input" | "progress" | "select" | "cancel" | "keydown" | "fullscreenchange" | "fullscreenerror" | "pointerlockchange" | "pointerlockerror" | "readystatechange" | "visibilitychange" | ... 85 more ... | "paste", listener: (this: Document, ev: MouseEvent | ... 14 more ... | ClipboardEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"input" | "progress" | "select" | "cancel" | "keydown" | "fullscreenchange" | "fullscreenerror" | "pointerlockchange" | "pointerlockerror" | "readystatechange" | "visibilitychange" | ... 85 more ... | "paste"'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: KeyboardEvent<Element>) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(event: KeyboardEvent<Element>) => any' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<Element>': altKey, charCode, ctrlKey, getModifierState, and 12 more.  TS2769

    61 |   useEffect(() => {
    62 |     if (shouldCloseOnEsc) {
  > 63 |       document.addEventListener(KEY_EVENT.KEYDOWN, escFunction, false);
       |       ^
    64 |     }
    65 |     return () => {
    66 |       if (shouldCloseOnEsc) {
```

Now if I change line `const escFunction: (event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => any = useCallback((event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => {` with `const escFunction: any = useCallback((event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => {` it compiles fine.

I am using react - 16.8.x create-react-app install.

Answer (score 10):

You have an event listener on document : `document.addEventListener(KEY_EVENT.KEYDOWN, escFunction, false);`

The `document.addEventListener` will call the callback (in this case `escFunction`) with a *native* keyboard event. However you have the callback `escFunction` annotated to accept a *React* keyboard event.

## Fix : Use the correct annotation

Change

```
const escFunction: (event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>)
```

To

```
const escFunction: (event: Event)
```

Comment: I am getting error `Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent'` on changing to `const escFunction: (event: Event) => any = useCallback((event: KeyboardEvent): void => {`

Answer (score 6):

`addEventListener('keydown'...` will fire a `KeyboardEvent`.

### So use:

```
const escFunction = (event: KeyboardEvent): void =>
```

`Event` will work partially, but will be missing some properties that you might need to access such as `.keyCode` or `.key`.