# "No overload matches this call" for removeEventListener and addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom-events, typescript-typings

I have a keydown handler function defined like so:

```
 handleOnKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    if (key.isEscape(e.key)) {
      stopEvent(e);
      this.props.handleClose(e);
    }
  }
```

However in another part of my code where this function is passed to `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener`:

```
componentDidMount () {
    const { current: modal } = this.modalRef;
    if (modal) {
      modal.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleOnKeyDown);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    const { current: modal } = this.modalRef;
    if (modal) {
      modal.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleOnKeyDown);
    }
  }
```

I get the following Typescript error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "keydown", listener: (this: HTMLDivElement, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLDivElement, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'KeyboardEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>': locale, nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>': altKey, charCode, ctrlKey, getModifierState, and 12 more.ts(2769)
```

What would be work around for this?

Comment: you'll need to show *where this function is passed to removeEventListener and addEventListener*

Comment: however, the error message is clear .... `Argument of type '(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLDivElement, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.`

Comment: As jaromanda implies, the error makes it look like you're assigning an event listener to an inappropriate HTML element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react typescript issue on addEvenListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162113/react-typescript-issue-on-addevenlistener)

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be answered this question:
[react typescript issue on addEvenListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162113/react-typescript-issue-on-addevenlistener)

The handler function for `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` does not accept a `React.KeyboardEvent` as a parameter.  It needs a DOM event.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Just use e: KeyboardEvent instead of React.KeyboardEvent

Comment: @IlijaLončarević Thank you, it works!