# TypeScript: Issues with KeyboardEvent/Event type and addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've coded a React burger menu that operates properly using regular JS/JSX but not with TS/TSX.

**The issue lies in my choice of type for the `keydown` event (as an argument for the `keyboardHandler` function), showing this error:**

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "keydown",
> listener: (this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, options?:
> boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
> Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.
> Type 'KeyboardEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': locale, nativeEvent,
> isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist

Overload 1 of 2 is linked to `keyboardHandler`'s subscription by the `addEventListener` upon component's mounting, overload 2 of 2 is linked its unsubscription upon unmounting.

```
import React, { FC, Dispatch, KeyboardEvent, useEffect } from "react";

export interface IBurgerMenu {
  toggled: boolean;
  navbar: boolean;
  setToggled: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

/* Props from Nav component */
const BurgerMenu: FC<IBurgerMenu> = ({ toggled, setToggled, navbar }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyboardHandler, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyboardHandler, true);
    };
  });

  // On/Off menu button
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setToggled(!toggled);
  };

  // Closes menu if escape key pressed
  const keyboardHandler = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      setToggled(false);
    }
  };

  return (
   // Irrelevant HTML
  );
};

export default BurgerMenu;
```

As suggested here: [react typescript issue on addEvenListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162113/react-typescript-issue-on-addevenlistener) & ["No overload matches this call" for removeEventListener and addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673494/no-overload-matches-this-call-for-removeeventlistener-and-addeventlistener) the following has been attempted:

- Using `Event` instead of `KeyboardEvent`. However, the Property `'key'` does not exist on type `'Event'`. `e.key` therefore becomes an issue.
- Using `any` as a type, which defeats the purpose of TypeScript.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't use reacts `KeyboardEvent`, typescript has its own declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the info Hozeis, I wasn't aware of this nuance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found here, thanks to [aim97](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7477881/aim97): [How to detect key pressed in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108197/how-to-detect-key-pressed-in-typescript)

All I had to do was add this interface on top of my code:

```
interface KeyboardEvent {
  key: string;
}
```